# Is it unsafe that these outdoor switches are on a lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, outdoor

I am in the process of replacing these two outdoor switches with one double gang unit. Reason being that between the two existing units I can see non-weatherproof wiring connecting them together. (Not visible in the image). Plus it's pretty ugly.

[image: two outdoor switches wired together]

On further inspection I've found that the power to these switches is the **ceiling lighting circuit from the floor below**. It's looped out of the building at ceiling level, then through the switch on the right and back into the building again.

The switches power an outdoor security light (linear halogen type) and two outdoor heaters. (We don't actually use the heaters, but suppose we did). The lighting circuit itself powers a dozen or so LED spotlights.

My question is firstly whether this is legal in the United Kingdom and secondly whether it is a sane or normal thing to do?

Should this wiring be fixed (by a professional of course) or am I good to just replace with double gang switch as planned?

Comment: I am on the other side of the pond so our rules are different. The NEC used in the US doesn’t have a requirement for lighting only circuits as it sounds like you are suggesting I would think that if the “ring” or what we call a daisy chain / branch circuit was properly protected (right size wire and circuit breaker) it should not matter in a residential setting where the power comes from.

Comment: I go through City Code and talk to them. They will ask for the wiring schematic. The questions they ask you too should be asking. Its always a learning experience. Best is when the Code Dept knows you are competent and you are working on your own home you can hire your very own Electrical Inspector the is approved by the City Code and he will help you so much you'll stop bothering your buds with questions and have solid "keep your home , your castle SAFE" answers. At first glance you are asking questions that have created doubt in your mind. Your questioning provides you with the answer.... ge